# Excel: number entered vs number displayed vs number stored in memory

Tags: excel, floating-point

How does excel determine what to number to display? specifically the number of decimal places

for example:

50.98, when stored as a single-precision float is 50.979999542236328125

50.979999 is also stored as the exact same single-precision float

(binary rep. 01000010010010111110101110000101, taken from here: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

when i type 50.98 & 50.979999 into 2 cells, change format to number, and extend out the decimal places using the formatting button

it represents them exactly as 50.98 & 50.979999, as i originally typed.

how is that working? is excel storing the exact text i typed and not (directly) storing the float data type at all?

if it stores it as a double, how does it preserve the exact precision i originally typed in that case?

i can't find documentation outlining how this works.

Note its not causing me any problems, i just need an explanation for differences in how excel displays vs calculations based on those values.

Comment: I suspect your tool is leading you astray.

Comment: It appears that the storage is 64 rather than 32 bits.  try:  https://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/Decimal.html

Comment: [Excel cheats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670589/is-google-sheets-less-or-more-accurate-than-microsoft-excel/62706896#62706896). It not only rounds numbers to attempt to conceal arithmetic issues, it rounds differently depending on the formula used in the cell. In this case, I suspect they are first converting the number to a 15- or 16-digit decimal numeral, even if you ask for more digits, and then converting that numeral to the requested number of digits (which then just adds zeros).

Comment: This [discussion](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/excel-2013-addition-error/0721db6d-77c0-484f-84f5-d223a4d00fcf) by joeu2004 on the MS forums might help

Comment: if it stores it as a double, it must separately store what rounding to apply for display purposes only right? so it stores more info than the standard double precision info.

Comment: Excel does not use 32-bit FP, thus the 3 paragraphs starting with "50.98, when store" are not relevant.

Comment: @chux, what does it use then? 0


"How does excel determine what to number to display? specifically the number of decimal places"

Comment: @PaMcD Google is your friend here [+excel floating point format](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/#:~:text=Excel%20store%2015%20significant%20digits,be%20stored%20in%20binary%20format.&text=So%20in%20Excel%2C%20it%20is,17%20when%20it%20is%20stored.)

Answer (score 1):

> it represents them exactly as 50.98 & 50.979999, as i originally typed.

Excel is padding with zeros after 15 significant decimal digits.

The internal number is encoded with a high enough *binary* precision such that limiting output to 15 *deimcal* places, the original typed in decimal values *appear* to be exactly that.

---

`=2/3` is an informative example showing this limit and exposing the binary internals by carefully extracting out a bit at a time.

As displayed in one cell, decimal output rounds to 15 places, padding with zero after that.

```
0.66666666666666700000000
```

The below does a binary conversion of `=2/3` and forms 0.10101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010101<sub>2</sub>, exactly what is expected if Excel used a [binary64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  (Below)

OP's observations are consistent with using binary64 and rounding output as decimal text to 15 significant digits.

---

```
Cell A3: =FLOOR(B2*A$1,1), Cell B3 = =B2*A$1 - A3
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hypothesis: When displaying a number, Excel first converts a number to a decimal numeral with at most 15 significant digits even if more are requested. If additional digits are requested, they are filled in as zeros. (In addition, [Excel may apply other alterations depending on context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670589/is-google-sheets-less-or-more-accurate-than-microsoft-excel/62706896#62706896).)

In Microsoft Excel 2008 for Mac, I entered `=1+22*POWER(2,-52)` in A1 and `=1+23*POWER(2,-52)` in A2. Using IEEE-754 binary64, these should generate the numbers 1.000000000000004884981308350688777863979339599609375 and 1.0000000000000051070259132757200859487056732177734375. Entering `=A1-1` and `=A2-1` in B1 and B2 and setting these to Number format with 30 decimal places shows “0.000000000000004884981308350690” and “0.000000000000005107025913275720”, which is consistent with IEEE-754 binary64. So we have some assurance the numbers above were indeed generated and stored in Excel.

Setting A1 and A2 to Number format with 20 decimal places shows “1.00000000000000000000” and “1.00000000000001000000”.

Clearly, if Excel were displaying the actual numbers with 20 decimal places, it would show “1.000000000000004885” and “1.000000000000005107”. It does not. The display we see is consistent with converting the numbers using 15 decimal digits (significant digits, not just those after the decimal point) and then padding with zeros.

Converting 50.98 to the IEEE-754 binary64 format yields 50.97999999999999687361196265555918216705322265625. Displaying this with 15 decimal digits yields 50.9800000000000.