# Reason for Number Conversion - Excel vs google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, data-conversion

I have an Excel sheet with a single number in it:

*2302392606141800.000000000000000*

[image: image of number in excel]

But the exact same sheet in google sheets is increased by 10:

*2302392606141810.000000000000000*

[image: image of number in google sheets]

I was wondering if anyone could tell me the reason for the discrepancy.

Thank you!

Comment: Excel will round all numbers to [15](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/rounding.htm) significant figures.  Anything over and
above this will be rounded to, whereas Google Sheets uses [16](https://nhigham.com/2013/03/13/how-accurate-are-spreadsheets-in-the-cloud/). My best guess is what you experiencing here is due to this phenomenon.

Comment: *"rounded to 0"**

Comment: @JvdV Would you consider posting this as an answer?

Comment: @Iamblichus. Well, I would if I was sure about it, it's just an educated guess that somehow the truncation of the figure is no longer 15 as per in Excel but went up to 16.

Comment: Have you looked at this answer?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670589/is-google-sheets-less-or-more-accurate-than-microsoft-excel